# How can I use '\' in SQL LIKE ... ESCAPE '\'

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, sql-like

I'm trying to delete all cache items where the description hasn't got a snap chat username in. I keep running into syntax issues when trying to escape the dash character?

Query:

```
$cacheItems = CacheItem::whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '% %'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '% :%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc\'%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc\_%' ESCAPE '\'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc \- %' ESCAPE '\'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc %'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc:%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%scm %'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%scm;%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc- %'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc.%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc-%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%SC -  %'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%Sc ~%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc ~%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc;%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc~%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%sc/%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snapchat:%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snapchat - %'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snapchat-%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snap~%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snap =%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snap•%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snap%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snap~%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snapchat%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snapchat ~ %'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%snap:%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%add my sc%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%add me on sc%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE '%add me sc%'")
      ->whereRaw("description NOT LIKE 'snap %'")
->get();
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%sc \- %' ESCAPE '\' and description NOT LIKE '%sc %' and description NOT LIKE '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `cache_items` where description NOT LIKE '%' and description NOT LIKE '%%' and description NOT LIKE '% %' and description NOT LIKE '% :%' and description NOT LIKE '%%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc\'%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc\_%' ESCAPE '\' and description NOT LIKE '%sc \- %' ESCAPE '\' and description NOT LIKE '%sc %' and description NOT LIKE '%sc:%' and description NOT LIKE '%scm %' and description NOT LIKE '%scm;%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc- %' and description NOT LIKE '%sc.%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc-%' and description NOT LIKE '%SC -  %' and description NOT LIKE '%Sc ~%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc ~%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc;%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc~%' and description NOT LIKE '%sc/%' and description NOT LIKE '%snapchat:%' and description NOT LIKE '%snapchat - %' and description NOT LIKE '%snapchat-%' and description NOT LIKE '%snap~%' and description NOT LIKE '%snap =%' and description NOT LIKE '%snap•%' and description NOT LIKE '%snap%' and description NOT LIKE '%snap~%' and description NOT LIKE '%snapchat%' and description NOT LIKE '%snapchat ~ %' and description NOT LIKE '%snap:%' and description NOT LIKE '%add my sc%' and description NOT LIKE '%add me on sc%' and description NOT LIKE '%add me sc%' and description NOT LIKE 'snap %')
```

Comment: Are you using special characters? `Sc` looks funny.

Comment: What framework are you using? And also your `SQL` statement is wrong.

Comment: Laravel framework, I understand my statement is wrong - would you help me figure out why?

Comment: What does `\-` mean? It is invalid in PHP and copied 1:1. And so mysql throws an error.

Comment: Easy way is to write down raw `SQL` , follow this rules https://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-and-or-not, and after that convert to Laravel Query style

Comment: And this one with `like` statement example https://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-like

Comment: mysql doesn't like ESCAPE '\'

Comment: Why are you trying to escape `_` and `-` characters? They have no special meaning in a SQL LIKE condition.

Comment: Underscores in `LIKE` match strings match a single character.

Comment: @O.Jones Huh, I honestly never knew that. Thanks!

Comment: `\ ` is the default escape character, so the whole `ESCAPE` clause could just be omitted with the same effect. That's the most reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You use `\` as your ESCAPE character in this:

```
  description NOT LIKE '%sc\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

That's a problematic choice because `\` itself gets used all over the place as an escape character at [MySQL's string-literal level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html), and also in various client software packages.

If this were my code I wouldn't trust `\` in this context at all (because I'm lazy and I don't want to figure out where and how it gets used as an escape character).

Either, best, choose some other escape character like this (`|` in this example)

```
  description NOT LIKE '%sc|_%' ESCAPE '|'
```

or double the `\` in the ESCAPE part of your sql, like this

```
  description NOT LIKE '%sc\_%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

(And, keep in mind that `column LIKE '%whatever'` is a notorious query-performance antipattern, because it can't use any index on `column`.)